# Download all music on Google Play iPhone App

Tags: iphone

With the Google Play iPhone app can you download your entire library without having to download each album induvidually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately not, you can however download entire playlists to your device, so that could be a way of getting around this.